# Can a view controller be a delegate of itself

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

I have a `UINavigationController` that has a bunch of `PhotoViewAViewController`s in its stack.

This happens because each `PhotoViewAViewController` has a button to add more photos and it chains them together.  There is also a `count` on each page of the total.

How do I update the `count`? I have read to do this use delegation. But can a class be a delegate of itself?

Also curious, can class A be a delegate of class B and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an instance of a class can be a delegate for itself, or you could have a circular delegate relationship. Neither of these situations are common though.

In your case you should post a notification when the count changes so that all interested controllers can observe the event and update.

Note that an alternative is to check and update the count in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials to posting a notifcation and grabbing it?

Comment: is this still relevant, even the deallocation? http://www.idev101.com/code/Cocoa/Notifications.html

Comment: Yes, it is. Not the call to super, but you must remove yourself from the notification centre before you're deallocated